# Display google map with boundary lines for each address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zillow

I am working on Google MAP API integration and I have tried to display the map with boundary lines for each addresses like Zillow.com.

Eg: http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/priced_sort/25.945776,-80.147139,25.9432,-80.152374_rect/17_zm/

Zillow gives a neighborhood api/db files with boundaries and I'm not able to make sense of it exactly. How to get map view like their view with the DB data.

I have addresses with latitude/longitude. Using these addresses and latitude/longitude can I draw the boundary line for each address? If the address specifies a building then it needs to display it with its boundary line. Is there any API from google MAP or third party?

Please give me suggestion on this - I went through google search results and related articles on this and couldn't get any result.